# Vim :belowright by default

Tags: vim

In vim, I prefer all of my splits, both horizontal and vertical, to be `:belowright`. I don't know why, it just feels more natural to me.

It gets annoying to `:bel sp foo.txt` instead of just `:sp foo.txt` all the time. Similarly with `:bel vs`. I have some workarounds (namely `map <leader>s :bel sp`), but my life would be made easier if there were a way to let vim know that `:belowright` should be the default for all splits unless otherwise specified.

Is there such an option? (I'm not above applying a small patch and recompiling.)

## Edit: Found it.

The answer is `set splitbelow` and `set splitright`. Should have poked around for ten more minutes before asking...

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it answered. Save a few clicks for those of us browsing unanswered questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set splitbelow
set splitright
```

Does the trick.